# Странное поведение Constraints в IB xCode 6

Tags: xcode, ios

После обновления до xCode 6 в IB стали "неправильно" выставляться constraint.
Отметил на изображениях интересующие моменты.

Если оставлять так, как на изображениях, то серый прямоугольник будет с белыми полями. Если выставить в -16, то часть серого прямоугольника вылезет за пределы экрана.

Как быть? Может быть, нужно новый переключатель передёрнуть?
[image]

[image]

Comment: если вы уж пользуете констрейны, почему у вас экран под телефон, а не квадрат стандартный?

Comment: @tragvar Так как xCode поменялся, а проект старый нет. Для вопроса новый проект делал.

Comment: @Zatoichy понял, спасибо.

п.с. у меня был такой переход по версиям, но проблемы с минус шестнадцать не было. А в основном я из кода задаю констрейнты, что и советую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение, не заметил галочку в "Add New Constraints".

[image]

Comment: Пометить как правильный ответ не могу. Странно.

Comment: Более того, если вы будете выставлять констрейнты к маржинам, то апп будет крашиться на верисях ос ниже 8, так как этот метод появился только в восьмерке.